# Merging master into main branch

Tags: git, github

I am attempting these days to have my master branch into my main branch (so I can start using as the default one), however, I am not being able to make it in GitHub.

After trying to open a pull request git does not detect differences between them and does not let me do the merging, although checking each branch, you can see all files from my project in the master and nothing in the main.

What can I do to fix it and why does this happen?

Comment: You can't merge two things that point to the same commit (consider them mutually merged). What if you merely rename the existing branch to `main` locally and remotely? I mean, isn't that, not merging, what you're looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to follow the "[Renaming the default branch from master](https://github.com/github/renaming)" official GitHub guide: there will be a native GitHub feature to do that in January 2021.

But if you don't have any pending pull requests, draft releases or branch protection policies, then you can

```
git switch -c main master
git push -u origin main
```

(Change the [default branch if the remote repository](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/changing-the-default-branch))

```
git push -d master
git branch -d master
```